# shortest path metric and induced usual euclidean metric

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Path metric is defined on path space $T_{x,y}(X)$ where $x,y\in X\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}:$
$$d(x,y)=\inf\{L(\sigma):\sigma\in T_{x,y}(X)\},$$ and $L(\sigma)=\sup\{\sum_{k=1}^{m}||\sigma(t_{k-1})-\sigma(t_{k})||:0=t_{0}<t_{1}<\cdots<t_{m}=1\}$ and $||(\cdot)||$ is the usual euclidean norm.

Here $T_{x,y}(X)$ is the set of all continuous functions on $[0,1]$ with $x$ as origin, ($\sigma(0) = x$) and $y$ as a destiny ($\sigma(1)= y$).

I am trying to see if the following examples agree with induced metric of usual eiclidean metric and path metric:

$X =\{x\in\mathbb{B}^n: x\neq 0\}, n\geq2,$ where $\mathbb{B}^n=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: ||x||\leq 1\}.$

$X= \{x\in\mathbb{B}^n: x\notin D\},$ where $ D=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},0)\in\mathbb{R}^n: x_1^2 +\dots+x_{n-1}^2\leq \frac{1}{2}\}, n\geq2.$

In both cases, when $n = 2,$ it seems metrics do not agree; for the first, in the unit disk I think is possible to give a sequence of paths between points $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$ which do not pass through origin and the limit of sequence is 2: I was considering for $k\in\mathbb{N}$ $$f_{k}(t)=(2t-1,\frac{1}{k}sin((2t-1)\pi))\space \space t\in[0,1],$$ but I cannot see if this path is in the unit disk.

For the second the interval $[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$ is missing but I cannot find a path for this situation.

Is there a easier path to prove this?

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced

Comment: Could you define what $T_{x, y}(X)$ mean? I suppose $\sigma$ is a path such that $\sigma(0)=x$ and $\sigma(1)=y$, right?

Comment: Thanks for answer. I edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll focus on the $n = 2$ case here but everything will extend to higher $n$.

It may be helpful to consider families of paths that are piecewise linear. So for your first example of $X$ we could conisder the path that consists of two lines: from $(-1, 0)$ to $(0,\epsilon)$ then from $(0,\epsilon)$ to $(1,0)$. We can define this path for all $\epsilon \in (0,1)$. As $\epsilon$ goes to $0$ the length of the path gets closer to the Euclidean distance between $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$. You can argue by symmetry that a similar argument will hold for any other pair of points such that the straight line connecting them passes through the origin. This will show that the Euclidean metric does agree with the path metric here.

For your second example of $X$ you can try a similar thing for the distance between $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$. If we take the piecewise linear path with vertices at $(-1,0), (-1+\epsilon, \epsilon), (1-\epsilon, \epsilon), (1,0)$. We can define this for all $\epsilon \in (0, 1)$ and simiarly to before we can take a limit as $\epsilon$ tends to zero. However the Euclidean metric does not agree with the path metric here. To see this, I'll give a hint to consider the distance between $(0,1)$ and $(0,-1)$.

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing you are using the usual euclidean norm. In this case, your path is not in the unit disk. Notice that:
$$f_1\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{2}, 1\right),$$

and this point does not belong to the unit disk for:

$$\left\|\left( \frac{1}{2}, 1\right)\right\|=\left[\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+1^2 \right]^{1/2}=\sqrt{\frac{5}{4}}>1.$$

Comment: Many thanks @PtF.